# C# dynamically change the value

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am pretty new at C# and I had to make a really primitive neuron app.
It works pretty good, except some values that don't update dynamically.

The problem is that when I change some values in the `numericUpDown` I want the current function(selected in a `comboBox`) to recalculate and change the value in the `richTextBox`(the result box)

I am sure it's just an event thing, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.Text=="Suma")
    {
        decimal s = 0;
        decimal temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
        {
            var currentNumUpDown =   this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            var currentNumUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            temp = currentNumUpDown.Value * currentNumUpDown2.Value;
            s = s + temp;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = s.ToString();
        Fin = s;
    }
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Produs")
    {
        decimal p = 1;
        decimal temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
        {
            var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            var currentNumUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            temp = currentNumUpDown.Value * currentNumUpDown2.Value;
            p = p * temp;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = p.ToString();
        Fin = p;
    }
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Minim")
    {
        decimal minim = 2;
        decimal temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
        {
            var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            var currentNumUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            temp = currentNumUpDown.Value * currentNumUpDown2.Value;
            if (minim > temp)
                minim = temp;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = minim.ToString();
        Fin = minim;
    }
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Maxim")
    {
        decimal maxim = -2;
        decimal temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
        {
            var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            var currentNumUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
            temp = currentNumUpDown.Value * currentNumUpDown2.Value;
            if (maxim < temp)
                maxim = temp;
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = maxim.ToString();
        Fin = maxim;
    }
}
```

I can provide more code if you need it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Subscribe to the numericUpDown.ValueChanged event. You can use the same method, `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` (though you might want to rename it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need an event for the NumericUpDown to recalculate the value.

try adding these events:

```
currentNumUpDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged); 
currentNumUpDown2.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Note that `Object sender` and `EventArgs e` will differ in the method, depending on which event called the method.

Comment: Using one control's event handler to handle another one's events is *not* a good idea. You can easily end up with with one control changing the other in an infinite loop

Comment: As long as he isn´t using the Sender and the EventArgs the code will work the same. But you´re right, this could cause some problems, still this solution will give him the idea of what he´s missing to solve the problem on his own.

Comment: yea, I tested it and it works. But the thing is I have a lot of numericUpDown's generated dynamically. It changes the value, but it pretty much kills the program. I stayed like 30 seconds to become responsive again after the value change.

Comment: What excactly did you do? Since the same method is called, the runtime shouldn´t increase (Execpt you call the method multiple times accidently).

Comment: I added the evens after declaring the currentNumUpDown's.

Comment: You could add a MessageBox at in the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` to find out when and how often it is executed. I don´t have any idea what else could cause the heavily increased runtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is exactly what he should do. Granted, renaming the method to something like `RecalculateOnChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)` might not be a bad idea. But there is no such thing as "one control's event handler": the method does not belong to the control. Its just a method, and it can be called from multiple places.

Comment: yea, I found the problem. It's because it's in a for. that way it it's executed way more than it should. But my variables are in a for and I cannot add the events outside of it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos With this method he isn´t chaing any control that could call that method itself, there are just multiple controls, that can fire this method which manipulates an `Result - RichTextBox` so there won´t be an ininite loop.

Comment: @BoantaIonut please provide the code of you for loop with adding the events

Comment: These are actually *problems*. A method's inputs should be passed in the parameter list. Conversions from string to text and vice versa should occure *outside* a method that calculates values. A method that requires a dozen controls to test, is simply untestable

Comment: @FatTony and that loop is why calculations shouldn't be perfomed in event handlers. Multiple event handlers could extract the inputs and pass them to the method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There´s no difference if you´re doing the calcuation in a method that is directly fired by the event, or if you´re calling the calculation method from a multiple methods, each distinctly belonging to a single control, you just have to build the method correctly

Answer (score 0):

@FatTony

```
if(comboBox1.Text=="Suma")
        {
            decimal s = 0;
            decimal temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
            {
                var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
                var currentNumUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
                currentNumUpDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
                currentNumUpDown2.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
                MessageBox.Show("executed");
                temp = currentNumUpDown.Value * currentNumUpDown2.Value;
                s = s + temp;
            }
```

Comment: Where do you add you `currentNumUpDown` to you form? put the `currentNumUpDown.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);` there so you will add them only once

Comment: Or if you´re working with some GUI designer like in visual studio, put the lines into the form_load event

Comment: That's the problem, I have to create the variables in every loop because I have to stock the current numericUpDown from a dynamic number of them. I couldn't see any other way I could check every numericUpDown.

Comment: with the following line you just create a reference to an already existing control: `var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;` So before running this method, somewhere you have to add these to your panel1.

Comment: finally I figured it out, thank you for your patience @FatTony

Answer (score 0):

```
void ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp_id = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Name.Remove(0, 14);
        if(temp_id[0]=='0')
        {
            temp_id = temp_id.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        int id = Int32.Parse(temp_id);
        decimal v1, v2;
        var numericUpDown1 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100+id).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
        var numericUpDown2 = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (200+id).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;
        var CurrentTextBox = this.panel1.Controls["Text" + (100+id).ToString()] as TextBox;
        if (numericUpDown1 != null && numericUpDown2 != null)
        {
            v1 = numericUpDown1.Value;
            v2 = numericUpDown2.Value;
            CurrentTextBox.Text = (v1 * v2).ToString();
        };
```

this is the custom event that creates the numericUpDown's taking the value form another numeriUpDown.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you´re trying to achieve with this programm and how you currently implemented this? Because either You don´t understand me, or I dont´t understand you.

Comment: somwhere in you code has to be something like `panel1.Controls.add([your numUpDown])` Otherwise `var currentNumUpDown = this.panel1.Controls["numericUpDown" + (100 + i).ToString()] as NumericUpDown;` won´t work.

Comment: as I said in the description, it is a neuron simulation for the neuronal networking class in college. It is supposed to get a number of synapses and it should calculate some stuff based on the information given.

Comment: I just had to ad the event where I created the numUpdown's and it worked like a charm.
num2.ValueChanged += ValueChanged;
num2.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

thank you very much! I couldn't figure it out by myself.